# Ajax call not returning only "data:

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a simple ajax call to test if I am connecting to the php file. I was trying to do a db_connect, but when that returned nothing, I dumbed it down to a blank php file with a simple echo. However, the alert() in my ajax function is returning the entire php page. I saw a question with the same topic, HOWEVER, my php contains no html. Therefore, that solution won't work. Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(function(){
    var request6 = $.ajax({ 
        url: "indexDb.php", 
        async: true, 
        type: "POST", 
        data: {func: 2}, 
        dataType: "html" 
    }).success(function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    })//end success
});
```

php:

```
<?
$value = $_POST['func'];

switch($value){     
    case 2:
        echo "made it";
        break;          
}
?>
```

Comment: So, first thing: `success` should be `done`. `success` is an ajax option, and `done` is the promise function. I don't think that alone explains all of your issues though.

Comment: @gotguts check my soluion

Comment: Looks like you got short_open_tags set to "Off" in your php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

change ? to ?php

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['func'];

switch($value){
    case 2:
        echo "made it";
        break;
}
?>
```

Short tags are disabled by default.

However to enable short tags enable the setting called short_open_tag in the php.ini file.

Comment: Oddly enough, this was actually the answer. I don't know why that is, because I have never had a problem with this before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: "html"` defaults to returning the entire response body, if the URL does not have a content type specified. Given that you say this behaviour is *not* the behaviour you wanted, I assume your php file is returning some kind of JSON string. If that is true, changing `dataType` to `json` will allow the script to make use of the php output regardless of the response's content type:

```
$(function(){
    var request6 = $.ajax({ 
        url: "indexDb.php", 
        async: true, 
        type: "POST", 
        data: {func: 2}, 
        dataType: "json" 
    }).done(function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    })//end success
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
$.ajax({  
          type:"POST",  
          url:"indexDb.php",
          dataType:"html",
          data:{func: 2},
          cache:false,
          success:function(data)
          { 
              alert(data);
          }  
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change dataType: "html" to dataType: "text". Hope this will help.